# Terms for how words connect?

Tags: grammar, terminology

Is there any terms for words that connect in specific ways?  For example,

Verb［ます stem］+ っぽい

［い］Adjective［remove the い］+ っぽい

［な］Adjective + っぽい

Noun + っぽい

Is what Bunpro lists for the grammar point ppoi https://www.bunpro.jp/grammar_points/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%BD%E3%81%84

Is there a catch all term for the pattern of words that you can place before ppoi?  They all seem to be nouns, but is there like a group of Japanese words that describe this connection pattern?

Comment: 接続 is commonly used in this context

Comment: Are you asking for a term denoting 'connection patterns' or a term for the connection pattern where the preceding word is noun-like?

Comment: A list of terms denoting connection patterns if they exist.

Comment: Maybe this is better for [linguistics.se]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a catch all term for the pattern of words that you can place before ppoi?

> but is there like a group of Japanese words that describe this connection pattern?

There is no catch-all term, but there are individual terms for each allowable word. In the case of っぽい:

1. noun (名詞)
2. verb stem or conjunctive form of a verb (動詞詞幹)
3. stem of an i-adjective (形容詞語幹)
4. stem of a na-adjective (ナ形容詞の語幹 or 形容動詞の語幹)

---

Grammar references vary in their terminology used to describe components of grammar patterns:

1. Makino and Tsutsui in [A Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar](https://bookclub.japantimes.co.jp/en/book/b309631.html) on page 337 defines the formation of -っぽい as:

   > (i) N っぽい
   >
   > (ii) Adj(*i*)stem っぽい
   >
   > (iii) Adj(*na*)stem っぽい
   >
   > (iv) V *masu* っぽい
2. Group Jamassy in [A Handbook of Japanese Grammar Patterns for Teachers and Learners](https://www.9640.jp/nihongo/ja/detail/?678) on page 250 defines the formations of っぽい as:

   - [Nっぽい]
   - [Rっぽい]

   In the explanation associated with っぽい on page 251, they describe the formation of っぽい as:

   > Used with a noun or verb stem to form *i-adjectives* to express the meaning "feels that way" or "has the tendency to."

   On page viii, they define N and R as:

   - N: noun
   - R: conjunctive form of a verb
3. Michiel "Pomax" Kamermans has a thorough list of verb inflections [here](https://pomax.github.io/nrGrammar/#section-7-Conjugation_Schemes), complete with grammatical terms in both English and Japanese.
4. 旅する応用言語学 explains verb stems (詞幹) [here](https://www.nihongo-appliedlinguistics.net/wp/archives/9131) page (in Japanese) using their own terminology.